# setting entity data adds to existing ones instead of replacing all existing values on Patch request

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this code in my ObjectServiceService. Every time I send a patch request, it adds to existing items and then it will have duplicates.

For example, at first I have items A, B, C. I send a patch request where I have removed ObjectServiceJob "C", so the request would contain A and B. After the request goes through, new items are A, B, C, A, B.

Also, the same happens when adding entities. If I have A, B and then add C, the list becomes A, B, A, B, C.

I don't really understand why it's doing this, it's the only place in my application where this isn't working the way I want it to.

```
public ObjectService modifyObjectService(PatchObjectServiceRequest request, Long id){
        ObjectService objectService = getObjectServiceById(id);
        objectService.createSnapshot();
        ObjectService editedObjectService = this.setObjectServiceData(request, getObjectServiceById(id));
        if (objectService.hasSnapshot()) {
            Map<String, SnapshotEntity.Change> changes = objectService.detectChanges();
            logService.saveLogTypeUpdate(editedObjectService, changes);
        }
        return editedObjectService;
    }

public ObjectService setObjectServiceData(PatchObjectServiceRequest request, ObjectService objectService) {

        if (request.getObjectServiceJobs() != null) {
            objectServiceRepository.save(objectService);
            List<ObjectServiceJob> objectServiceJobs = new ArrayList<>();
            request.getObjectServiceJobs().forEach(serviceJob -> {
                ObjectServiceJob objectServiceJob = new ObjectServiceJob();
                objectServiceJob.setObjectService(objectService);
                objectServiceJob.setJob(serviceJob.getJob());
                objectServiceJob.setWorkDetail(serviceJob.getWorkDetail());
                objectServiceJobRepository.save(objectServiceJob);
                objectServiceJobs.add(objectServiceJob);
            });
            objectService.setObjectServiceJobs(objectServiceJobs);
        }
        return objectServiceRepository.save(objectService);
    }
```

This is how ObjectService entity contains ObjectServiceJobs:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "objectService")
    @SnapshotIgnored
    private List<ObjectServiceJob> objectServiceJobs;
```

And this is the ObjectServiceJob entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "object_service_job")
public class ObjectServiceJob extends SnapshotEntity implements SnapshotCompatible {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "serial")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "object_service_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private ObjectService objectService;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_id", nullable = false)
    private Job job;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "work_detail_id")
    private WorkDetail workDetail;

    @Override
    public String getSnapshotString() {
        return job.getName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to do a bit more than just create a new list and expect JPA to do automatically delete, update everything for you.

I would say you need to iterate through existing `objectServiceJobs` and check:

**1)** If it is new then: add job to the list and set the  `objectService` on its ManyToOne association.

**2)** If it does not exist anymore: remove job from the list and set `objectService` on its ManyToOne association to NULL.

**3)** If job already exists and it should remain in the list then just call `save()` passing the job to update its data.